# Appropriate method for updating contents when WebAPI returns

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have a Web API class which handles all network communication and downloads in my project. My project contains both collection views and tableviews which are updated whenever a download is complete.

My way to handle this feels ugly.

I pass references to my collection views/table views to the methods in **WepAPI.m**. 
Whenever a download is complete I use the references to insert new objects to my views and to send reload messages.

Is this the way to go? Should I use **KVO** or some other method instead?

I am using **AFNetworking** Framework to handle my web communication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use blocks.

For example: (in WebAPI.h)

```
typedef void (^SomeStuffBlock)(id someStuff);
- (void)getSomeStuffWithCompletion: (SomeStuffBlock)completion;
```

Use a singleton so that the downloader stays in memory. (Put this in your WebAPI.m)

```
+ (id)sharedInstance {
static dispatch_once_t once;
static id sharedInstance;
dispatch_once(&once, ^{
    sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
});
return sharedInstance;
```

}

Calling would be like this:

```
[[WebAPI sharedInstance] getSomeStuffWithCompletion: ^ (id someStuff) {
    //Make changes to your views here
}
```

This ensures that the view changes you make are done in their corresponding view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

an easy pattern should be to use two singletons:

- a ConnectionManager, which handles auth, timeout, parsing,
- a DataManager, which asks the ConnectionManager to fetch the endpoints and store the parsed results.

Then you can use KVO (or NSNotifications) to listen to any updates to your DataManager singleton.

This way of doing things is simple enough and provides a fair amount of reusability for each of the components involved.